# Передать данные из формы в БД(phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, sql

пишу код на php, вроде все подключено ошибок не выдает, но и данные не записываются в БД

```php
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
$mysql = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($mysql->connect_errno) exit('Error connecting to');
$mysql->set_charset('utf8');
if(isset($name) AND isset($pass)){
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, "INSERT INTO peoples (`name`, password) VALUES ('$name', '$hash')");
}
$mysql->close();
$name = $_POST['test1'];
$pass = $_POST['test2'];
if(empty($pass)){
  echo 'Поле не заполнено';
}
elseif(isset($pass)) {
  $hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  echo $hash;
}
?>
```

Comment: Нормально так - сначала выполнил запрос, а потом установил переменные для запроса.

Comment: Меняю местами код, все так же безрезультатно, может быть проблема в том, что я записываю результат запроса в $result и на этом все, а следовало бы результаты этой переменной передать в БД?

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо, ошибка найдена!